# JComboBox get item

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have a quick question. I don't get it...

I've got a JFrame where I add a JComboBox:

```
            JComboBox<String> Team_ComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        Team_ComboBox_Handler ComboBox_Listener = new Team_ComboBox_Handler();
        Team_ComboBox.addActionListener(ComboBox_Listener);
        Team_ComboBox.addItem("Test 1");
        Team_ComboBox.addItem("Test 2");
```

On this Frame I have a button which opens another JFrame.

```
            Play = new JButton();
        Play.setText("Play");
        Play.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        Play.addActionListener(menuhandler);
        private class main_menuhandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==Play){
                teams Team = new teams();
                Team.teams();

                disposeMainMenue();
            }
            if(e.getSource()==Close) {
                System.exit(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyway, I would like to transfer the Selected value of the Combobox to a method of the other class. I know how I can get the itemvalue of the combobox in the method itself (with getselecteditem) But how can I do that in the ActionPerformed Method as I can't access the combobox in the ActionPerformed method.... I created another ActionListener (comboBox_Listener) but I haven't put any code into it...

Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please follow coding standards; one of many documents regarding this: http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues appear to me:

Your main question:

> But how can I do that in the ActionPerformed Method as I can't access the combobox in the ActionPerformed method

Your likely best solution is to change your code and variable declaration placement so that you **can** access the JComboBox fromt he actionPerformed method. If you're declaring the combobox from within a method or constructor, change this so that it is a proper instance field of the class.

Other problems:

- You should not be creating multiple JFrames. If you need a dependent window, then one should be a JDialog. If not, then consider swapping views with a CardLayout.
- Learn and follow Java naming conventnions so others can better understand your code. Class names begin with capital letters and methods and variable names don't for instance.
- I am not sure why you're doing this: `System.exit(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`. Why pass that constant into the exit method?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! I knew I missed something.

Comment: I definitely need to get used to naming conventions

Answer (score 2):

Use a constructor for your action listener class:

```
private class main_menuhandler implements ActionListener {

    private JComboBox<String> Team_ComboBox;

    public main_menuhandler(JComboBox<String> Team_ComboBox){
        this.Team_ComboBox = Team_ComboBox;
    }
}
```

Now you can create the class `main_menuhandler`via the constructor and add the combobox to it.
In your Overriden action you have access to it.

Try playing around with this as your code snippet isn't broad enough to actually provide proper code. But this should answer your question

Comment: This will work well, and will make it easier should the OP wish to make the handler class a proper separate class. 1+

Comment: A bit of design patterns and fragments instead of multiple frames would also solve this, but the OP is likely to be a beginning programmer and will only be more confused, hence a imo 'dirty' solution